# IntelliJ IDEA not able to run as described

Tags: intellij-idea, snapcraft

I followed installation of IntelliJ IDEA as described in the following session.

[Install IntelliJ IDEA as a snap package on Linux](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/install-and-set-up-product.html)

`sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic`

And it says ...

> When the snap is installed, you can launch it by running the intellij-idea-community

When I actually run it as follow:

`intellij-idea-community`

Command 'intellij-idea-community' not found, but can be installed with:

`sudo snap install intellij-idea-community`

I got the above error

So when I try listing snap
`sudo snap list`

```
Name                     Version    Rev   Tracking  Developer  Notes
core                     16-2.32.8  4650  stable    canonical  core
gnome-3-26-1604          3.26.0     64    stable/…  canonical  -
gnome-calculator         3.28.1     167   stable/…  canonical  -
gnome-characters         3.28.0     86    stable/…  canonical  -
gnome-logs               3.28.0     31    stable/…  canonical  -
gnome-system-monitor     3.26.0     39    stable/…  canonical  -
intellij-idea-community  2018.1.4   51    stable    jetbrains  classic
```

And this is the

```
snap version
snap    2.32.8+18.04
snapd   2.32.8+18.04
series  16
ubuntu  18.04
kernel  4.15.0-22-generic
```

On ubuntu 18.04

I have no idea where I made mistake.

Comment: Can you run other commands installed via snap? Have you tried to re-login? Check your [snap directory structure](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snaps/structure) to see the installed application. Can you run it from snap `bin` folder?

Answer (score 1):

intellij-idea-community binary is in /snap/bin, which needs to be added to PATH. Don't know why this is not done automatically or mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Using snap is prerequisite for you? Otherwise consider using [Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/).

You can install any Jetbrains product and it manages updates automatically. You can even rollback to a previous version in case of trouble.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: Sorry I just want to share my experience. I already tested different options to install and to maintain the installation of IntelliJ. My conclusion is using Jetbrains Toolbox is a lot easier. Of course, as I said above, if snap is not a prerequisite.